# Auto layout in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

I am learning auto layout and try to implement this tutorial

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

it all working fine for other but iPad. In iPad is show something like this [on portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A1XD.png)

but when i rotated it show as expected.

have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have only 3 views in the view controller. It's quite likely that you placed another view by accident.

You can also try UI debugging and eveything will be clear: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html

Comment: it show as expected on other device and also on landscape . ....edit: silly mistake .Thanks

Comment: try view debugging then